# Dataframe.to_csv(sep=";") ends with newline instead of ";", how to replace newline (\n)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have this dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and want to turn it into a csv file with one line:

```
1;0;1;1;0;0;1;
```

I tried this:

```
df.to_csv("filepath/filename.csv", index=False, header=False, sep=";")
```

and the result is:

```
1;0;1;1;0;0;1\n
```

How do I replace the newline with a semicolin before creating the csv file?
I dont want to create, open it and then replace it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. I get a CSV with a single column, one digit per line. Which is what I expect, since the dataframe is initialized with a dict of key (=column name) - list (row values) items. So you're doing something else in between the creation and writing of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`line_terminator`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```py
df.to_csv("filepath/filename.csv", index=False, header=False, sep=";", line_terminator=";")
```

Answer (score 0):

`sep` is the field delimiter value.
You can set the line terminator with `line_terminator`.

Try:

```
df.to_csv("filepath/filename.csv", index=False, header=False, sep=";", line_terminator="")
```